# Why in a multiprocessor, all the CPUs are not evenly utilized?

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing

I have just starter researching on the multi core architecture and have a question in mind.
I have an test application, which takes the number of thread as argument, create those threads, set the affinity (with help of sched_setaffinity), and then have a busy loop (while (1)) in every thread task.
I am using a Fedora 19 VM (3.11.9-200.fc19.x86_64) with 4 processors. Now when I create 4 threads, set their affinity to 4 different processors, the CPU utilization is not even.
It is like,

PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND

2113 root      20   0       0      0      0 R 92.90 0.000  18:22.91 multicoretest

2114 root      20   0       0      0      0 R 92.23 0.000  18:07.29 multicoretest

2112 root      20   0       0      0      0 R 49.28 0.000   9:41.48 multicoretest

2111 root      20   0       0      0      0 R 48.61 0.000   9:42.17 multicoretest

2110 root      20   0       0      0      0 Z 0.000 0.000   0:00.00 multicoretest

Can anyone give me an explanation, why the 3rd and 4th cores are not as busy as the first two although they have same thread function?

It will really help a lot.

Thanks

Comment: Are all those actual cores, or virtual cores due to HyperThreading?

Comment: Can you show output of `lscpu` command ?

Answer (score 3):

I can think of at least a couple of possible reasons for this behavior:

- Your program is not the only one executing. Any other programs, as well as the OS itself, use the processors, which may not permit your program to fully utilize the available CPU power. Even with the CPU affinity set, the process scheduler still affects how much CPU time will be available for your threads.
- The CPU cores are virtual and thus not fully independent. For example [hyper-threaded cores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) in Intel processors share most of their physical logic networks. Since your tasks are both mind-numbingly simple and completely identical, threads executing on the same physical core will compete for its resources.

Comment: These sound like pretty strong candidates given the scenario.  In more complex systems where there aren't simple tasks running on exactly the number of threads as cores or hyper-threaded cores, you'd need to understand how [Instruction Pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipeline).  Modern systems go through instructions and find dependencies and align those instructions on the same processor.  Also, some systems will work both outcomes of a branch as to not lose time if the branch was not as predicted.  Either way thkala's comments likely apply to the given situation.